# Update router in Angular 2

Tags: angular, npm, angular-routing

I'm new in Angular and npm. Today I trying update router in Angular2 from `2.0.0-rc.1` to `3.0.0-alpha.3`. For this, I change version router in root file package.json on `"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.3"` and make command 'npm update'. Files in `@angular/router` were changed, but now console in browser show error message for my app :

> "http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/router.umd.js 404
>   (Not Found)". This file does not exist in the project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are going from rc update to Alpha??? do you want to update angular 2.0.0-rc-1

Comment: Sorry, do not quite understand. I'm just trying update only router component to 3.0.0-alpha.3 and don't touch any other components of angular. It is possible?

Comment: yes you can but its not best solution as there might be change angular 2 handling For same Router version

Comment: Angular 2 website same example can check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router-deprecated.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks **[@rinukkusu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1961059/rinukkusu)**

```
// No umd for router yet is the comment in the SystemJS config file for 
packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
```